# Azure web app is 503 Service Unavailable. How do I get it back running?

Tags: azure

Our website has been hosted on Azure for a few years. Tonight it is throwing 503 Service unavailable errors. I cannot even load a url to a .jpg file. I have restarted the app and still nothing loads from the website. I cannot buy Azure support because I have bought and cancelled Azure support in the past. We are a 3 person business and depend on our small website and it is down and I don't know what to do. None of the trace logs make any sense to me.

Comment: Now 3 hours later it works. I have no idea why. Scares the hell out of me that our site can work fine for years, I change nothing. It goes down with 503 errors for a few hours and then poof it is back up. I am going to look into AWS. I need to sleep and depend on my host.

Comment: Are you using the Free or Shared plans?  If so, check the quotas: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-subscription-service-limits#app-service-limits

Comment: For my case it was Azure Front Door and Accept-Encoding header  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/troubleshoot-issues

Answer (score 13):

I think 503 could mean that you reached a quota and Azure now respond with a 503 for requests. So I would check the Quotas section within your App Service Plan. 
Also check:
[Troubleshoot HTTP errors of "502 bad gateway" and "503 service unavailable" in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-http-502-http-503)

Comment: when app is stopped (e.g. due to billing issues) Azure WebApp returns 403.
503 is problem rather with e.g. startup of the application

Answer (score 3):

There are several things you can do to help remedy the situation.

- Restart the application (please indicate what it is that will help
  us)
- Restart the instance that the application is running on.
- Restore from a previous working backup of the site.

You should also add more information to your post so we can help, like what application you are using e.g. Apache, Nginx ect.

Answer (score 2):

I've also had a similar problem. I had two deployment slots and in the first slot (production) which I had the latest code and in the second slot, I've missed deploying the latest code and configured traffic as 60-40 which gave me hard time finding it.

Once I've set 100% to the production slot it started working.

Just thought to share this in case it could be useful if you come across the same stuff in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Please be noted that you will get the same "Service Unavailable HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable." error when you developed your app for 64 bit platform and your web app is configured with 32 bit.

You can change this from the configuration. Go to the Configuration from the left side-bar under settings, and then click on the `General settings`, change the `Platform` dropdown value undewr the `Platform settings` to `64 Bit`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**For us it was a result of the remote debugger.** Disabling remote debugger and restarting the app service fixed the 503 error. I think one dev was remote-debugging while another was deploying the app and that seems to have caused an issue under the hood of the app service that broke port binding (we were seeing a stack trace in logs about failing to bind to port).

Comment: This was the issue for me as well. The 'restart' button on Azure App Services is tucked away. Make sure you follow these steps:

1. Open Azure Web Services

2. Click "Diagnose and solve problems"

3.Type "restart" in the search bar and click "Advanced Application Restart"

4. Select the server and click restart!

Answer (score 1):

For me it was "Path mappings" in "Configuration".

As soon as i added a new Azure Storage Mount, the application broke.

Setting my Storage account -> Networking, to "Enabled from all networks" fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

My problem with the same was solved with removing the CI deploy option:
error "app service is offline" azure.
Azure App Service deploy

```
Take App Offline
Select the option to take the Azure App Service offline by placing an 
app_offline.htm file in the root directory of the App Service before the 
sync operation begins. The file will be removed after the sync operation 
completes successfully.
```

Tick to off/disabled
Then I removed the app_offline.htm on the app servie via Kudu DebugConsole cmd...

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was in port when I checked the logs.

To resolve this I added WEBSITES_PORT = 8080 in the applications settings in the Azure portal.

DONE!!!